# Android: What are the steps to publish a Facebook application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After finishing my Android application which uses Facebook APIs and uses permissions that require Facebook approval, what are my next steps?

Do I need to publish it first on Google Play then contact Facebook to check the application if it follows their regulations? Or do I send them a copy of my application APK file to check it first and grant me their approval?

What are the permissions that I can get as an individual not a company?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get the same permissions as an individual and as a company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send it to Facebook first before you upload it to google play. The last thing you want to do is upload the app to google play and accepted and then Facebook rejects it as people will download the app and will think it's broken and could cause bad reviews from the get go.

I'm not 100% certain however I'm pretty sure individuals can get the same permissions as a company can. I recently worked on an app that integrated facebook and was able to get account information etc with no issues at all.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good news ... What about the condition of beta testers that I have to select to test my app before it gets approved by FB, how many beta testers are required? And when I invite them, is the invitation being send with my name?

Comment: You don't need to have any bet a testers at all, at least according to FB policy.  If you add beta testers to your app, there is no automatic notice sent, so you are free to send whatever invitation you like